# Is using a const method from one object thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am not sure if this is a duplicate, I have looked through many posts but they do not seem to be close enough to my question.

I want to use a const method from one object to change other objects concurrently. The program basically needs me to move a particle under the influence of gravity and I want to run this in parallel for all particles.  I made a physics class and in that class I have a const method to move a particle object.

Here are some example classes to understand me better.

```
/**
 * Particle.h
 */
#ifndef __Particle__sim__
#define __Particle__sim__

class Particle {
  private:
    double height;
    double velocity;
  public:
    const double getHeight() const;
    const double getVelocity() const;
    void setHeight(const double&);
    void setVelocity(const double&);
};

#endif
```

---

```
/**
 * Physics.h
 */
#ifndef __physics__sim__
#define __physics__sim__

#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "Particle.h"

class Physics {
  private:
    double gravity;
    double timeStep;
    void moveParticle(Particle&, const double) const;

  public:
    Physics(const double g, const double t);
    void moveParticles(std::vector<Particle>&, const double) const;
};

#endif
```

---

```
/**
 * Physics.cpp
 */
#include "Physics.h"

using namespace std;   

Physics::Physics(const double g, const double t) : gravity(g), timeStep(t) {}

void Physics::moveParticle(Particle& particle, const double time) const {
  // move particle under gravity
}

void Physics::moveParticles(vector<Particles>& particles, const double time) const {
  vector<thread> threads;
  threads.reserve(particles.size());

  for (auto& p : particles) {
    threads.push_back(thread(Physics::moveParticle&, this, std::ref(p), time));
  }
  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }
}
```

---

Here is essentially my main

```
/**
 * main.cpp
 */

#include <vector>

#include "Physics.h"
#include "Particle.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<Particle> particles;
  // insert 100,000 particles

  Physics physics = Physics(-9.81, 0.01);

  physics.moveParticles(particles, 5.0);    

  return 0;
}
```

So is `physics.moveParticle(Particle&, const double)` thread safe here?

Short & Sweet:
I want to use a method from one Physics object to make multiple threads to move all the Particles in my program and I am not sure if the const method I wrote is thread safe. I can't see why not but I can't justify it.

Comment: What does *move particle under gravity* do?  That seems important.

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__Particle__sim__`, `__physics__sim__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Note that spawning 100,000 sub-threads is likely to set your computer on fire, metaphorically speaking... :)  most modern OS's aren't really made to scale beyond a few hundred active threads at one time.  You'd probably be better off dividing your particles list into a set of N sub-lists, where N is the number of CPU cores in the computer the program is running on, and spawning off one thread per sub-list.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the insight. I will do this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, this should be thread safe.

We need to see the implementation of Particle::setHeight to be absolutely sure. What if it did something like write to a global array? Which would be silly but we can't tell for sure.

However, your Particle looks very simple. What would be even more thread safe is to not mutate it at all. Make them immutable and create a new one with each calculation.

You can still change them by assigning the new Particle back to the old Particle.

However if you really want to get into threading, a great technique here is to have two world states: previous and next. These swap with each update step. Each update step reads from previous and writes into next. This lets other threads like graphics display read from previous without constantly locking on little things like Particles.

With that, a immutable Particle does not slow anything down at all. In fact, the compiler will rewrite the machine code for `nextParticles[i] = updateParticle(prevParticles[i])` into direct assignments to its final position in memory. That's RVO or NRVO.

Comment: @fred.smalley: Return Value Optimization and Named Return Value Optimization is where the compiler takes the return value from a function and constructs it directly in the caller instead of building a temporary value in the function and then copying it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks thread-safe to me.  In particular, if the only (non-immutable) data read or written by each of the spawned threads is the thread's own corresponding Particle object, then there is no shared data as far as the threads are concerned.  (The Physics object itself is shared, of course, but since you are not modifying the Physics object during the sub-threads' lifetime, the Physics object is effectively immutable/read-only during the operation, and any read-only access to the Physics object by the spawned threads will not be a source of race conditions)